# copy varibles to mat into matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a simple task to do

```
p=1:5
p=[1 2 3 4 5]
```

I want to copy this many times into one matrix

e.g. mat=zeros(2020,1) in one column

however, I want to copy this in order or index

```
index=(index + 4 )
```

so every 5 rows I will get 1 to 5 each time until the end of the matrix

mat will filled with all elements of p from 1 through 5 until the end of size mat column wise

as example

```
mat = [1 ;2; 3; 4; 5; 
1; 2 ;3; 4; 5
1 ;2; 3; 4; 5; 
1; 2 ;3; 4; 5........]
```

Comment: [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat the vector `2020 / 5 = 404` times:

```
p = (1 : 5).';
mat = repmat(p, 404, 1);
```

The trick here is to transpose your vector `p` so that it's a column vector, then  you simply have to repeat along the rows 404 times to give a 2020 element vector of repeating 1 through 5s.

---

If I can suggest something else, you can avoid using `repmat` by simply declaring a vector from 0 up to 2019, but then use `mod` - the modulus operator with the divisor being 5 and adding 1 to ensure that you will get the possible values going from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4:

```
mat = mod((0:2019).', 5) + 1;
```